# How to partition SD card using LG G Vista as card reader(without root)

Tags: rooting, adb, lg, partitions, formatting

I am trying to root my G vista but all the methods I have found so far require an sd card formatted to EXT2 partition. I do not have an external reader so my only option is to use the phone as a reader. I have found some methods to do this with ADB but all of them require root. Other forums have said that I should be able to format it directly from settings but the option doesn't show up for me.

Either a good approach to formatting the sd card through the phone or a root method that doesn't require a formatted card would be nice.

I am running ubuntu but can switch to windows if that would make my life easier.

Comment: Where did you see that you need to format you SD card to root your device. I haven't seen that anywhere.

Comment: All of the tutorials to root a G Vista have said that I need to boot from the sd card in recovery mode and to do that I need to format the sd card, or so I"ve been led to believe

Comment: Can you give me a link to the tutorial(s). I have rooted without an SD card. You can boot into recovery with an SD or flash using a computer tool